# How to operate transformers at lower voltage than nominal

Tags: transformer

What do I need to watch out for when I operate a power transformer at a significantly lower primary voltage than it is rated for?

How do I derate the power handling capability? Is efficiency degraded significantly?

I would expect that, for the same power, core losses are decreased (magnetic field scales with the voltage). Resistive losses on the other hand scale with the current, so will increase. I am wondering if these are the only effects.

Comment: More importantly, magnetic field scales with *current*. Current scales with voltage only as long as the impedance remains constant.

Comment: @DaveTweed Does it in a transformer? My impression was that the current in primary and secondary act against each other to decrease the flux in the core. Lenz' rule.

Comment: Yes, the *currents* produce magnetic fields that cancel. Nothing to do with voltage, except indirectly, as I noted above.

Comment: I agree :) In a transformer however, the core flux is exactly proportional to the EMF. It is largely independent on the load resistance.

Comment: Assuming the current/voltage is AC of course...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operating a transformer at a lower voltage than rated is just fine. As it's voltage that determines the field in the core (for an ordinary AC power transformer, things are calculated differently for a flyback), you're running further below saturation, so have lower core losses.

Unfortunately the same limitations apply to current as for running at the full voltage, it's the temperature rise of the windings. As you've less core heating, you can probably get away with a little extra current for the same overall transformer heating.

Lower voltage and same current means lower power throughput. Although core losses have fallen, the copper losses will be the same, so the overall efficiency is probably worse (for a 'normal' power transformer, MOTs with their huge fields are probably more efficient running at half rated voltage).

Comment: For a typical power transformer, isn't the iron loss typically quite a bit less than copper loss? Which way is the heat usually transferred, copper to iron, iron to copper or mostly iron to air and copper to air?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the helpful answer! Seems my intuition wasn't far off. @CharlesCowie I figured it would basically boid down to that exact question. Quick research indicates that copper losses do indeed dominate at high load.

Comment: Conversely, this also means that the reduced core losses result in a very higher no-load efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

You need to watch the current rating of the windings which will remain the same.

e.g. 230 V, 100 VA transformer will have a primary current, \$ I_p = \frac {100} {230} = 0.435 \ \text A \$. Dropping the primary voltage to half and using the same current will derate the transformer to \$ P = VI = 115 \times 0.435 = 50 \ \text {VA} \$.